# Local Image not unloading

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have local image loaded in to div.

```
backgroundImage: 'url('file://c:/image.jpg')'
```

But the problem is if I will delete or replace `c:/image.jpg`
my div image will stay the same(with old non existent image) even If I will re-mount the component.
Image will be stay the same. Only restating the application will work.
How can I refresh image?

Comment: Are you using webpack or any build system? Maybe create-react-app?

Comment: why you are not using relative path, or not keep all resource inside project assets?